# Angular Material Tabs: Content outside mat-tab

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to display the tabs `<mat-tab-group><mat-tab>` in the `<mat-toolbar>` in my header component, those tabs needs to change the content in other components.

```
// Component 1
<mat-toolbar-row>
  <mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="First"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Third"></mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</mat-toolbar-row>

......

// Component 2
<section>
  // Content of Tab 1
</section>
<section>
  // Content of Tab 2
</section>
<section>
  // Content of Tab 3
</section>
```

Or should I just create my own component and style it the same way instead?

Comment: play with tab index.

Comment: Yes that should work. I was thinking the other way around where the tabs change the content. Thanks.

Comment: Did you found any solution to it ? aside of creating a custom one? thanks.

Comment: @alexOtano Yes, you have tab indexes change as Abhishek suggested, you just need to play with the current selected index and with `ngif` you hide or show the one you want.
An idea would be to put the tabs on an array of objects, then on tab change you just need to loop through those and get the exact one you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First" #firstTab> </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second" #secondTab></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
<div [ngStyle]="{ display: !firstTab.isActive ? 'none' : null }">First</div>
<div [ngStyle]="{ display: !secondTab.isActive ? 'none' : null }">Second</div>
```